# mkdir() not creating folder on linux server

Tags: php, mkdir

Right I had this working on my local server which was windows server 2012, however when hosting I am now on a linux server.

when the user submits the form it should run this code

Code:

```
$target_dir = "docs". "/";
//IF/ELSE the folder is already created...
    if(!file_exists($target_dir . $ref . "/"))
    {//Create folder named 1 inside the customer ref folder.
        mkdir($target_dir . $ref . "/" . "1" . "/", 0775, true);
        $count = 0;
    }else
    {//Create new folder inside customer ref folder 
        //count the amount of folders inside docs/$ref/
        $find_folders = glob($target_dir . $ref . "/" . "*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        $count = count($find_folders);
        //create new folder inside $ref/ using count+1 to make the folder increase by 1
            $new_folder = $count +1;
            mkdir($target_dir . $ref . "/" . $new_folder . "/", 0775, true);        
    }
            //IF count exists then the $target_file changes to the new folder...
                if($count > 0)
                    {
                        $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . "/" . $new_folder . "/";  
                    }else
                    {//else use first directory
                        $target_file = $target_dir . $ref . "/" . "1" . "/";
                    }
```

On my windows server every single "/" you see i was using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR but asumed being linux it would need to be changed to a forward slash. This is now not working. Any dieas why?

Comment: `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` determines which way the slashes need to go depending on the OS you're using. You didn't need to change them going from Windows to Linux, that's the whole point of them. That said, you should need to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` at all, PHP is smart enough to work out which way the slashes go and converts them if needed.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions?

Comment: Have you checked your servers log files to see if there are any errors?

Comment: basic debugging: look at the paths you're buliding. don't build/use them directly inside the mkdir call. Build them separately so you can capture the values. `$path = $target_dir . $ref . etc...; echo $path; mkdir($path)`.

Comment: infact it could be the permissions on the folder , let me check

Comment: i do have the permissions to write